# How does `try / catch` work in details

Tags: java, exception, stack

I would like to the innards of how does `try {} catch {}` block and stack traces work.

I was reading [this great article about exception handling anti-patterns](https://today.java.net/article/2006/04/04/exception-handling-antipatterns) and found the following paragraph:

> ```
> catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
>   throw new MyServiceException("Blah: " +
>       e.getMessage());
> }
> ```
>
> This destroys the stack trace of the original exception, and is always wrong.

After that I realized that I don't *really* know how `try/catch` works. My understanding is the following. Consider the example:

```
void top() {
    try {
        f();
    } catch (MyException ex) {
        handleIt(); 
    } finally {
        cleanup();
    }
}

void f() {
    g();
}

void g() {
    throw new MyException();
}
```

When I call `top()`, the call chain  `top -> f -> g`
leaves two [stack frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Structure) on the call stack (for `top` and `f` functions). When the exception is raised in `g`,
the program bubbles up the execution stack until it finds `try/catch` block that handles the exception. Meanwhile it frees the stack frames and attach stack trace information to some "magic" object that can be passed to `catch` and the stack trace can be printed.

How does it know that the called function is "surrounded" with the try/catch block? Is this information bound to the stack frame? Like, a pointer to error handling block (some switch selecting a matching `catch` block), and a pointer to `finally` block? Why `e.getMessage()` is destructive in the example above (see the comments)?

Note, I *know* how to use try/catch and exceptions, I want to know how does it work *inside*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"How does it know that the called function is "surrounded" with the try/catch block?"

The code of each method contains [Exception Table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.5) which describes all try-catch blocks of that method.

When a procedure (function, method) is called, the current stack frame is appended with the address of the calling instruction, so as to restore execution of that frame at the correct instruction (next after calling instruction).

When a throw statement is executed, the JVM [examines each stack frame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.10)  to find out if that frame can handle the exception. It can if its method contains a try-catch block which contains the calling instruction, and the type of block's exception is a supertype (or the same as) of the thrown exception. If such a frame is found, the frame restores its execution from the instruction pointed to from the try-catch block.

Answer (score 4):

When an exception is thrown, the complete calling-stack information is attached not to some magic object, but to the exception object that is created. This doesn't happen while the exception "bubbles up" - it happens when it is created and it always contains the full call-chain.

The called function doesn't need to know it is surrounded by a try-catch-block, it just creates an Exception-object that contains the call-chain and passes it up to the calling method. This method has to decide wether it handles the Exception because it is caught by some catch-clause or if it passes it further up. Exception that aren't caught bubble up till they reach the top of the calling-chain and the VM handles them - usually by printing the stack-trace and terminating.

Regarding the `e.getMessage`-example:
The full stack-information is contained only in the original exception. In the given example that original Exception object e is discarded, only the contained message is passed on to a newly created Exception-object. And that Exception only "knows" its own calling stack, so the original information attached to e is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Lower level method just throws exception and we should handle them in upper level. Consider your example. It should like this

```
void top() {
try {
    f();
} catch (MyException ex) {
    handleIt(); 
} finally {
    cleanup();
 }
}

void f() throws MyException {
try{
   g();
}catch(MyException e){
  throws new MyException("Error in g()",e); 
}

}

void g() throws MyException{
throw new MyException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exception are propagated up the call stack, from the method that initially throws it, until a method in the call stack catches it. If a method A calls B, and B calls C then the call stack looks like this:

```
A
B
C
```

When method C returns the call stack only contains A and B.
Exception are propagated up the call stack, from the method that initially throws it, until a method in the call stack catches it.

When an exception is thrown the method stops execution right after the "throw" statement. Any statements following the "throw" statement are not executed. The program resumes execution when the exception is caught somewhere by a "catch" block.

If a method calls another method that throws checked exceptions, the calling method is forced to either pass the exception on, or catch it. Catching the exception is done using a try-catch block.If no exception is thrown by any of the methods called or statements executed inside the try-block, the catch-block is simply ignored.If an exception is thrown inside the try-block, for instance from the divide method, the program flow of the calling method, callDivide, is interrupted just like the program flow inside divide. The program flow resumes at a catch-block in the call stack that can catch the thrown exception.

If an exception is thrown inside the catch-block and that exception is not caught, the catch-block is interrupted just like the try-block would have been.

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/basic-try-catch-finally.html
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flow-control-in-try-catch-finally-in-java/